# Exactly what causes E_CORE_ERROR and E_CORE_WARNING?

Tags: php, error-handling, php-internals

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) states that E_CORE_ERROR are fatal errors that occur during PHP's initial startup:

> This is like an E_ERROR, except it is generated by the core of PHP.

Also, it states that E_CORE_WARNING are warnings that occur during PHP's initial startup:

> This is like an E_WARNING, except it is generated by the core of PHP.

How exactly does E_CORE_ERROR and E_CORE_WARNING occur?

Specifically, what will cause them?

Comment: Are you getting these errors? I assume they would be caused by some problem with the installation of PHP.

Comment: @Barmar, no, I'm on some code that are supposed to deal with them and I'm wondering *what* actually causes them

Comment: http://lxr.php.net/search?q=E_CORE_ERROR&defs=&refs=&path=&hist=&project=PHP_5_4 and http://lxr.php.net/search?q=E_CORE_WARNING&defs=&refs=&path=&hist=&project=PHP_5_4 should tell you exactly when they happen

Comment: @PeeHaa, Sounds like an answer, pity I can't read C well yet, Someone that answers this will get a necro + revival badge.

Answer (score 3):

You probably run PHP >= 5.4 where for example safe_mode got removed and if you still have it enabled, PHP throws that `E_CORE_ERROR` error.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php